# Transfer and transmit

Tags: meaning

Does the word 'transfer' have the same meaning as 'transmit'?

I look up in the dictionary, and it says 'transfer' means move and 'transmit' means pass. But they seem to be used similarly sometimes. For example, "Bacteria may be transmitted in a variety of ways" and "MPSA and other bacteria are transferred from one person to another."

In addition, if there is a multiple choice exercise:

"•Long false eyelashes are prone to collect bacteria and dust, which can be _____ to the eyes.

A. Transferred B. Transmitted"

Which one will be the better answer?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Transfer is usually an active, voluntary movement of something between two persons, or used informally. Transmit is the more correct medical/biological term; I don't have any real data on this, so just a comment, not an answer